# Javascript for Variations with Repetition of missing string characters with multiple arrays of options

Tags: javascript

I have a 25 character code that I know some of the characters for but am missing the remaining characters. I have the following code so far to help solve the missing code options:

```
function combinations(w) {
var x = new Array(
         "B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K",
         "M","P","Q","R","T","V",
         "W","X","Y","Z",2,3,4,6,7,8,9
    ),
    n = w.match(/\!/g).length,
    x_n = new Array(),
    r = new Array(),
    c = null;

for (var i = n; i > 0; i--) {
    x_n.push(x);
}

c = x_n.reduce(function(a, b) {
    var c = [];
    a.forEach(function(a) {
        b.forEach(function(b) {
            c.push(a.concat([b]));
        });
    });
    return c;
}, [[]]);

for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < c.length; i++, j = 0) {
    r.push(w.replace(/\!/g, function(s, k) {
        return c[i][j++];
    }));
}

return r;}

console.log(combinations("6X3#!-#!KHY-BgVDT-W!WDV-H6HJR"))
```

For the 25-character code "7X3!!-#!KHY-BKVDT-W!QDV-H6HFR" this code does a great job of listing all the possible outcomes for all of the spaces with a "!".

I would like to take this a step further to refine my results. I am trying to figure out how to make the spaces with the "!" choose from one set of possibilities, and make the spaces with the "#" choose from a different set of possibilities, and still end up with a list of all possible outcomes.

The second set of possibilities would be something like:

```
var p = new Array(
        "B","D",
        "P","R",
         2,8)
```

Comment: What is the question, since it is obviously not "Can someone write this for me"?

Comment: @ScottHunter Homework?

Comment: The question is how do I set up the code to include the second set of possibilities? I have tried many different ways to do it but none of them work. I am not very experienced in this field.